# Page migration fails from CMA(contiguous memory allocator) area

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am facing problem With CMA. I am trying to allocate device memory through CMA(contiguous memory allocation) for my ARM based target board running linux 3.8 kernel.

While requesting memory allocation through private cma node, it results "NO memin CMA area". Eventhough we have reserved required memory. While debugging "_alloc_contig_migrate_range" function we found that Migration of some pages failed and resulted in NO mem in CMA area.

While pages satisfying following condition in "migrate_page_move_mapping(migrate.c)"  function are being migrated.

```
   if (!mapping) {
            /* Anonymous page without mapping */
             if (page_count(page) != 1) {
                         return -EAGAIN;
             }
             return MIGRATEPAGE_SUCCESS;
   }
```

other pages fail and  returns in migrate_page_move_mapping() from

```
    if (page_count(page) != expected_count ||

                radix_tree_deref_slot_protected(pslot, &mapping->tree_lock) != page) {

                        spin_unlock_irq(&mapping->tree_lock);

        return -EAGAIN;

    }
```

Whereas page_count(page) -->3 and expected_count-->2  doesnt match and hence returns -EAGAIN repeatedly.

While looking at the page flags I found following diffrence in flags.

Migration success-> 0xc3a40059

Migration  fail->       0xc3a0000d

Diff in flags is

Observation flags-->
                PG_dirty
                PG_active
                PG_swapbacked
                PG_referenced

Migration success---->
 SET
 SET
 SET
 NOTSET

Migration fails------>
 NOTSET
 NOTSET
 NOTSET 
 SET

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of reasons why CMA migration could fail on kernels older than 3.18  are documented
**[here](https://chengyihe.wordpress.com/2015/08/12/kernel-mm-cma-allocation-failure-due-to-buddy-system/)** *(buddy allocator accounting error)* and **[here](https://chengyihe.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/kernel-mm-cma-allocation-failure-1/)**(KSM migration NOT supported).

> Contrary to popular belief, the **Contiguous Memory Allocator** framework in the Linux kernel
>   does NOT gurantee the availability of the contiguous memory throughout the lifetime of the system.

The core concept of CMA is as follows...

1. At boot, allow certain amount of memory to be defined as the contiguous buffer pool.
2. At runtime, permit allocating memory from this contiguous buffer pool for regular memory allocation requests (as a last resort).
3. Whenever request for a large contiguous buffer is made,

   a. immediately migrate the pages allocated in **step2** above into the regular memory pool.

   b. provide a large contiguous buffer to the requester.

The problem lies in the fact that under certain situations,
migrating the pages in step **3a** can fail. This could be due to:

- the lack of **free memory** or **swap** as a destination to migrate the non-contiguous small pages already allocated in the CMA pool.
- the ability of processes to [pin memory/buffers](https://lwn.net/Articles/600502/) allocated to them.

As there was no consesus on a single approach to update/replace CMA, it has continued to exist in its current form working most of the time, but not guaranteeing contiguous memory under all possible circumstances. With the advent of SMMUs and scatter-gather DMA support for other controllers, there is lesser need for large contiguous buffers.

---

That said, there are 2 major approaches to improve CMA that have been tried and found acceptance in some circles:

1. [**GCMA**](https://lwn.net/Articles/619865/)
2. [**ZONE CMA**](https://lwn.net/Articles/633101/)

Both approaches have their own limitations based on the compromises they find acceptable.